# Oracle UCM - What will UCM do when content expired?

Tags: oracle, oracle-ucm, content-expiration

Is there any service or job schedule that called every minute to execute expired content?
I want to override that service.

Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `execute expired content`? What exactly you want to do with expired content?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you somehow would like to prevent the expiration of certain content items. There is a service, EXPIRE_UNEXPIRE_DOC_BY_NAME, used to expire (and unexpire) content (I am not sure if this service is always used):

```
This service is used to expire or unexpire documents in the Content Server.
@param dDocName The document to expire or unexpire.
@param action Should be set to 'expire' or 'unexpire'.
```

You could hook into the above service and override its functionality.

The following service lists expiring and expired items.
[GET_EXPIRED](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e11011/c04_core.htm#BABBADHG):

```
The optional isExpiredQuery parameter, when set to true, causes the service to list only items that have already expired.

Without this parameter, the list also contains items that are scheduled to expire within the range of dates specified by endDate and startDate. This may include items that have already expired if the start date is earlier than the current system time.
```

There is also a ScheduledEvent, [EnableExpirationNotifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10726/c06_core_ref043.htm), which will send an email listing content items which are about to expire. You could hook into this event and do something with the items it returns.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering my question. I was thought EXPIRE_UNEXPIRE_DOC_BY_NAME is the only one service to expire the content. But this service only triggered when we click the button to force expire the content.
And I finally got my own question. 
There is a job schedule which called every minute, also the javaMethod to expire the content.
The service is PROCESS_STATIC_RENDITION_JOBS in ziprenditionmanagement_service.htm.
Note that we can only edit this service directly, but cannot override the service outside this component.